# Problem with my inner join

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have the below LINQ query. `FactColumns` is a list of `FactColumn` objects and `SelectedColumns` is a list of strings. I want to get a list of `FactColumn` objects using an inner join on `SelectedColumns`. However, I am getting `null` for below query.

```
var lst = from fc in this.DataSetFact.FactColumns
          join column in m_TableDataDict[tableGuid].SelectedColumns
              on fc.Name equals column
          select new
          {
              fc.ColumnType,
              fc.DataType,
              fc.FriendlyName,
              fc.Name,
              fc.ParentFactName,
              fc.Size,
              fc.State
          };
```

Why am I getting `null`?

Comment: Is the dataset reloaded? Keep in mind even though two rows are from the same source (database) and contain the same data if they are reloaded the .NET will create a new reference and unless class has equality operator .NET compares by reference which returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see above code running fine. Check if data is loaded properly.

Sample

```
    List<FactColumn> FactColumns = new List<FactColumn>();
    List<string> SelectedColumns = new List<string>();
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FactColumns.Add(new FactColumn() { DataType = "int", Name = "int" });
        FactColumns.Add(new FactColumn() { DataType = "string", Name = "string" });
        SelectedColumns.Add("string");
        var lst = from fc in this.FactColumns join column in SelectedColumns on fc.Name equals column select new { fc.DataType,  fc.Name};
        foreach (var column in lst)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(column.Name);
        }
    }

    public class FactColumn
    {
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

What about this using lambda:

```
var lst = this.DataSetFact.FactColumns.Where(hm=>hm_TableDataDict[tableGuid].SelectedColumns.Contains(hm.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your join.  Since you do not seem to be using any information from that I would change it to be a where statement.  Try this:

```
var lst = from fc in this.DataSetFact.FactColumns
      where m_TableDataDict[tableGuid].SelectedColumns.Contains(fc.Name)
      select new
      {
          fc.ColumnType,
          fc.DataType,
          fc.FriendlyName,
          fc.Name,
          fc.ParentFactName,
          fc.Size,
          fc.State
      };
```